# Java Transformer not writing unicode symbol in CDATA section

Tags: java, unicode, emoji, cdata, transformer-model

My goal is to write a String containing the xmldata into a XML file.

But for some reason unicodes are not written into the cdata sections properly but rather end up outside of them.

For example:

With the string received containing `...<TAG><![CDATA[Save ߒ¾ Test]]></TAG>...` the wanted content of the file is:

`<TAG><![CDATA[Save  Test]]></TAG>`

But after transforming it turns out as:

`<TAG><![CDATA[Save ]]><![CDATA[ Test]]></TAG>`

Which results in problems when wanting to read the file.

Here the code for the function:

```
public static void saveFile(String fileName, String xmlData) throws Exception {
OutputStream out = null;
Writer writer = null;
try {
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  InputStream iStream= new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  Document document = dBuilder.parse(iStream);

  TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, document.getXmlEncoding());

  out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
  writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, document.getXmlEncoding());
  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new Exception("Could not export XML-File!", e);
} finally {
  CommonUtil.close(writer, out);
}
```

}

For reference the corresponding node in the document object also contains the whole text:

`[[#cdata-section: Speichern ߒ¾ Test]]`

Am I missing something or has anyone run into a similar problem before?

Comment: What kind of problems does it cause when reading the file? It's perfectly valid XML.

Comment: I'm not into all tricky details of XML and encodings. But `<TAG><![CDATA[Save  Test]]></TAG>` might be invalid as CDATA sections cannot contain surrogate blocks. And in UTF-16, a surrogate block is needed to represent . So the transformer might actually do only correct thing.

Comment: @Codo Thanks for your response and the problem arises because the xml file is imported through a different function and is expecting one cdata section with all of the text inside it. Importing works perfectly fine actually if the  is in the cdata section. Will look into surrogate blocks though, thanks again.

Comment: The code that does the importing is **broken.**  There are a number of easy ways to read an element’s text content that will not depend on whether a single contiguous Text or CData node is present, like [Node.getTextContent()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) and [XPath.evaluate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @Codo Surrogate blocks are not needed (and should never be used) if the XML document’s encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: I'm aware of it. Yet the XML standard explicitly mentions it, thereby mixing up two different things: XML and Unicode encoding. As the XML formatter likely does not know what encoding will be used, it might assume the worst, i.e. UTF-16 with surrogate blocks, and split the CDATA section.

Comment: @VGR should have specified that the importing code part isn't done in Java but rather in PLSQL, Java only calls a function with the data of the xml file as a clob

Comment: You may find that `dbFactory.setCoalescing(true);` (before creating the DocumentBuilder) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who commented on the question. @VGR and @Codo

Sadly setCoalescing didn't quite do the job for what I wanted to do.

Using dom4j helped at the end as I was able to use XMLWriter and an OutputFormat to write the String in the formatted way with the text "staying" in the CDATA Section. This of course doesn't make the XML file valid, having surrogate blocks in the section as VGR mentioned and doesn't make the solution good but it does what is needed.